# How to write the SQL query such that I can get successive number of events?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query to count the successive number of events. Here is what I am expecting in a pictorial form:

[image]

Can you help me with a SQL query that will achieve this result?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Tag updated to mysql

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: From your screenshot, we can't even tell for sure, what sorting criteria should be applied - which is of course important, because without a _defined_ order, there is no "successive" either. Is the application_id your criterion here, or is there a date field, ...?

Comment: Why the amount for `person2` is 1 whereas there are two rejects - for application_id 2 and 4?

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version (show output for `SELECT VERSION();`).

Comment: Even the column headed number of max succesisve rejections is odd and doesn't match title.

Comment: @Akina With less than a year for MySQL 5.7 to reach end of life I think we should MySQL 8.x by default.

Answer (score 1):

Without having a complete dataset, it is difficult to take into account the corner-cases, but I would approach it like this. Also, I feel that the number of successive rejections could not be 1 (i.e. if there are not 2 events in a row, there are no successive events):

```sql
WITH step1 AS (
 SELECT
    app,
    status,
    LEAD(status) OVER (PARTITION BY app ORDER BY application_id) AS next_status
 from table1)
 
SELECT app, COUNT(status)+1 AS no_successive_rejections
FROM step1
WHERE status = next_status
AND status = 'REJECTED'
GROUP by 1
```